# VB.NET Console and RichTextBox difficulties

Tags: vb.net

I am new here. I am very happy that I joined this website, because everyone here is so smart!
Now, let's cut to the chase! Hopefully, I will be able to explain everything properly.

I am creating a Visual Basic application. It's supposed to reassemble a so-called "fake programming language." It's having some issues though.

Let me show you an example before explaining:

```
If RichTextBox1.Text.Contains("console output >'insert comment';") then
   Console.WriteLine("insert comment")
End If
```

Now, what I want here is a custom input. (if someone types "I want cookies" then I want the console to say that!
For instance, if I type:

```
If RichTextBox1.Text.Contains("console output >'Insert something here';") then
    Console.WriteLine("Whatever the user wrote!")
End If
```

I just want to possibility to write whatever I want, that's all! I hope I made myself clear, because I am having a hard time explaining here. Help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You've got a form application trying to write to the console?  It doesn't work that way.  It's either one type of app or another.  Hacks are probably possible, but are beyond the scope of a newb... er, new programmer.

Comment: Yes, it works. I am using a Form Application and a Module. The Module1.vb represents a Console Application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match just the part with the `console output >` and then replace that portion of the string with empty space, like this:

```
If RichTextBox1.Text.Contains("console output >") Then
    Console.WriteLine(Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, "console output >", ""));
End If
```

Comment: It's working! You are a genius! Although, there's another issue... If I type: console output > what?, and then something after it... (like: console output > what? [ENTER] and --> it shows up on the console too.

Comment: Ok, I am confused, you do not want everything after the `console output >` to be echoed to the console?

Comment: Not exactly. I want it to be like this; console output > "text. What goes after the last " should not show up on the console. Like    console output > "text" [ENTER] I like cookies [DEBUG] Console = text. I hope I made my self clear! Thank you!

Comment: Okay, can you post in your original question the scenarios that do not work with my answer?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Replace(RichTextBox1.Text, "console output >", "highlighted"))` I just want the highlighted text to show up on the console. `console > highlighted` I changed the code to `Console.WriteLine(Replace(RichTextBox1.SelectedText, "console output >", ""))` and whenever I drag and select the word, it will show up on the console. What goes after the `console output > highlight` should not show up on the console. If you don't have any more answer, I will mark your first answer as an accepted answer. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.